# Instance Initializers in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection

We are getting through the long slog of updating our ember-cli application to its latest iteration. We fell very much behind. I am at the stage where instance initializers have been introduced and I am getting the feeling this is going to break the way in which I have implemented a certain initializer currently.

```
export function initialize(container, application) {
  var store = container.lookup('store:main');

  // We need a basket to be present when
  // the application loads. Wait for this
  // to happen before continuing.
  application.deferReadiness();

  store.findOrCreateRecord('order', basketToken).then(function(basket) {
    container.register('basket:main', basket, { instantiate: false });
    application.inject('controller:basket', 'model', 'basket:main');

    // Let the application know we have
    // a basket and can continue.
    application.advanceReadiness();
  });
}
```

What is now recommended is that I split this up into a "normal" initializer to register the basket object and an instance initializer to grab the store and make the call to our API server. Doing this however I would not have access to the registry within the instance initializer to register the returned object from my promise which I would then inject into my controller. I assume I am thinking about this all wrong, but I have not been able to wrap my head around it. Any suggestions how I should by updating this?

Comment: I think this explanation by @tomdale will be usefull for you https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10256#issuecomment-113846021

Comment: Thanks @artych. This addresses some very valid points and has made me think about my current implementation. I will attempt to accomplish what I want to do in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's reasonable to post  [@tomdale explanation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10256#issuecomment-113846021) here as an answer to help others with understanding initializers.

**@tomdale**: "It's not possible to defer app readiness in an instance initializer, since by definition instance initializers are only run after the app has finished booting.

Sidebar on the semantics of application booting: "App readiness" (as in, `deferReadiness(`) and `advanceReadiness()`) refers to whether all of the code for the application has loaded. Once all of the code has loaded, a new instance is created, which is your application.

To restate, the lifecycle of an Ember application running in the browser is:

1. Ember loads.
2. You create an Ember.Application instance global (e.g.
   App).
3. At this point, none of your classes have been loaded yet.
4. As your JavaScript file is evaluated, you register classes on the
   application (e.g. `App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend(…);`)
5. Ember waits for DOM ready to ensure that all of your JavaScript
   included via `<script>` tags has loaded.
6. Initializers are run.
7. If you need to lazily load code or wait for additional setup, you can call `deferReadiness()`.
8. Once everything is loaded, you can call `advanceReadiness()`.
9. At this point, we say that the `Application` is
   ready; in other words, we have told Ember that all of the classes
   (components, routes, controllers, etc.) that make up the app are
   loaded.
10. A new instance of the application is created, and instance
    initializers are run.
11. Routing starts and the UI is rendered to the
    screen.

If you want to delay showing the UI because there is some runtime setup you need to do (for example, you want to open a WebSocket before the app starts running), the **correct solution** is to use the `beforeModel/model/afterModel` hooks in the `ApplicationRoute`. All of these hooks allow you to return a promise that will prevent child routes from being evaluated until they resolve.

Using `deferReadiness()` in an initializer is an **unfortunate hack** that many people have come to rely on. I call it a hack because, unlike the model promise chain in the router, it breaks things like error and loading substates. By blocking rendering in initializers, IMO you are creating a worse experience for users because they will not see a loading or error substate if the promise is slow or rejects, and most of the code I've seen doesn't have any error handling code at all. This leads to apps that can break with just a blank white screen and no indication to the user that something bad has happened."